# Spring-security does not work properly

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-security

The application is supposed to only give access to ROLE_ADMIN users to /secret addresses but it does not give access to anyone (either authorized or non authorized ones), another problem is that even when I enter a wrong username and password it allows to sign in and does not redirect to error.page.

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web- 
app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
    </listener>
     <context-param> 
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/medics-security.xml 
            /WEB-INF/login-service.xml
        </param-value> 
    </context-param> 
    <filter> 
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
        <filter-class> 
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy 
        </filter-class> 
    </filter> 

    <filter-mapping> 
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**medics-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns='http://www.springframework.org/schema/security' 
        xmlns:beans='http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans' 
            xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' 
            xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd'>

<beans:import resource='login-service.xml'/> 
<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/error.jsp">
    <intercept-url pattern="/register*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secret*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.html" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"/> 
    <remember-me/>
    <logout/>
</http> 

<authentication-manager> 
    <authentication-provider> 
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <user name="user" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
        </user-service>   
    </authentication-provider> 
</authentication-manager> 
</beans:beans>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
   <beans xmlns='http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans' 
                xmlns:context='http://www.springframework.org/schema/context' 
                xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' 
                xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd'>


    <context:component-scan base-package='com.myproject'/> 
    <bean id='internalResourceResolver' 
                 class='org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver'> 
        <property name='prefix' value='/Web Pages/'/> 
        <property name='suffix' value='.jsp'/> 
    </bean> 
    <bean 
     class='org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping'/>
    <bean class='org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter'/> 
    <bean id='placeholderConfig' 
                 class='org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer'/> 

    <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
        </value>
    </property>
  </bean>
   <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

**j_spring_security_check.java**

```
public class j_spring_security_check {

    public String execute(){
        System.out.append("here in spring check.java");
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="html"/> 
    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
        </result-types>


        <action name="*">
            <result type="tiles">{1}</result>
        </action>

        <action name="j_spring_security_check"   
        class="com.myproject.struts.j_spring_security_check">
            <result name="SUCCESS" type="tiles">register</result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

**register.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>secret page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>register</p>
        <a href="secret.jsp">secret</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove this code:

```
<action name="j_spring_security_check"   
class="com.myproject.struts.j_spring_security_check">
    <result name="SUCCESS" type="tiles">register</result>
</action>
```

from struts.xml. Normally you do not need to handle this URL. Spring Security has built-in filter responsible for processing of credentials.

Try to replace your

```
<intercept-url pattern="/secret*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

pattern by

```
<intercept-url pattern="/secret.jsp*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

if you have single `secret.jsp` page.